# PSQL import fails: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "id"

Tags: postgresql, csv, heroku, import

I exported the users table from my Heroku-hosted sql db. The export looks fine, but when I try to import it, I get `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: "id"`

This is the command used, per the Heroku site:

```
\copy users FROM ~/user_export.csv WITH (FORMAT CSV);
```

EDIT:
I didn't include this, but the error also includes:
`CONTEXT:  COPY users, line 1, column id: "id"`

I had done programmer math and translated that to a zero-based format, but maybe it's the header that's the issue?

-- ANSWER: YES. argh.
/EDIT

I've found some posts in different places that seem to involve JSON fields, but the schema is fairly simple, and only simple objects are used:

```
                                   Table "public.users"
      Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |       Default       
------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------
 id               | uuid                     |           | not null | 
 name             | text                     |           | not null | 
 username         | text                     |           | not null | 
 password_hash    | text                     |           | not null | 
 created_at       | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 updated_at       | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 tournament_id    | uuid                     |           |          | 
 background       | text                     |           |          | 
 as_player        | boolean                  |           |          | 
 as_streamer      | boolean                  |           |          | 
 administrator    | administrator            |           | not null | 'no'::administrator
 creator          | boolean                  |           | not null | false
 creator_approved | boolean                  |           | not null | true
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "uq:users.username" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (username)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "tokens" CONSTRAINT "tokens_userID_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("userID") REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "tournament_player_pivot" CONSTRAINT "tournament_player_pivot_playerID_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("playerID") REFERENCES users(id)
```

The table the data was exported from and the table I'm trying to import to have the identical schema. I've come across suggestions that there is a specific single-quoted format for UUID fields, but manually modifying that has no effect.

What is the problem here?

This is a sample from the export file using a testing user:

```
id,name,username,password_hash,created_at,updated_at,tournament_id,background,as_player,as_streamer,administrator,creator,creator_approved
ad5230b4-2377-4a8d-8725-d49cd78121af,z9,z9@test.com,$2b$12$97GXVp1p.nfke8L4EYK2Fuev9IE3k0WFAf4O3NvziYHjogFCAppO6,2022-05-07 06:03:44.020019+00,2022-05-07 06:03:44.020019+00,,,f,f,no,f,t
```

Comment: This issue is solved: I'm leaving it here in case anyone else finds it useful: upshot is, either don't export headers, delete headers when importing, or specify file has header when importing (I assume this is doable).